# When switching from Minitest to RSpec in Rails, how to make `rails test` (or `rake test`) run the RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, minitest

When [adding RSpec to Rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#installation), we can finally run `rails spec` (or `bundle exec rspec`) to run the RSpec tests.

However, `rails test` confusingly still attempts to run the (non-existent) Minitest tests.
How can the "test" rake task be configured to run the RSpec tests instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `test` task like this:

```
# Add the code below in the Rakefile
require File.expand_path(‘config/application’, __dir__)

Rails.application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['test'].clear

task :test do
  Rake::Task['rspec’].invoke
end
```

Another way (I only tried in my console with a task that puts something but it should work with rspec):

```
# Add the code below in the Rakefile
require File.expand_path(‘config/application’, __dir__)

Rails.application.load_tasks
task(:test).clear.enhance([‘rspec’])
```

Comment: Very interesting! The second approach does not seem to work. The first one does partly: Afterwards, `rake test` works, but `rails test` will still run minitest.